# what is the name of the timeout exception in App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, exception

For some reason, I was under the impression that it was just called Timeout, but it doesn't seem to be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timeout exception handling is explained in the [Request Timer](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#The_Request_Timer) section of the docs:

> A request handler has a limited amount of time to generate and return a response to a request, typically around 30 seconds. Once the deadline has been reached, the request handler is interrupted.
>
> The Python runtime environment interrupts the request handler by raising a `DeadlineExceededError`, from the package `google.appengine.runtime`. If the request handler does not catch this exception, as with all uncaught exceptions, the runtime environment will return an HTTP 500 server error to the client.
>
> The request handler can catch this error to customize the response. The runtime environment gives the request handler a little bit more time (less than a second) after raising the exception to prepare a custom response.
>
> ```
> from google.appengine.runtime import DeadlineExceededError
>
> class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
>   def get(self):
>     try:
>       # Do stuff...
>
>     except DeadlineExceededError:
>       self.response.clear()
>       self.response.set_status(500)
>       self.response.out.write("This operation could not be completed in time...")
> ```
>
> If the handler hasn't returned a response or raised an exception by the second deadline, the handler is terminated and a default error response is returned.
>
> While a request can take as long as 30 seconds to respond, App Engine is optimized for applications with short-lived requests, typically those that take a few hundred milliseconds. An efficient app responds quickly for the majority of requests. An app that doesn't will not scale well with App Engine's infrastructure.

The DataStore has its own [TimeOut exception](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/exceptions.html)

> The `google.appengine.ext.db` package provides the following exception classes:
>
> [...]
>
> `exception Timeout()`
>   Raised when the datastore operation exceeds the maximum amount of time allowed for datastore operations.

Comment: Not true. First a catchable exception is thrown, and after a reasonable interval, an uncatchable one is thrown.

Answer (score 7):

For datastore calls, the exception is google.appengine.ext.db.Timeout. For total (wall clock) duration exceeded, the exception is google.appengine.runtime.DeadlineExceededError. The DeadlineExceeded error is thrown 'soft' once, at which point you have a short time to return a response and exit; if you don't, it's thrown again, uncatchable, and your script is unceremoniously terminated.