# Which exception App Engine raises when a task nears the 30 second limit?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, exception, task, task-queue

From [Task Queue Python API Overview](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview.html#Task_Execution):

> If your task's execution nears the 30
>   second limit, App Engine will raise an
>   exception which you may catch and then
>   quickly save your work or log process.

Which exception is that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the name of the timeout exception in App Engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923957/what-is-the-name-of-the-timeout-exception-in-app-engine)

Comment: Maybe. But I need to be sure it is the same exception. Thinking better, should be, since task workers are request handlers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception is `google.appengine.runtime.DeadlineExceededError`, the same was with normal web requests.  A task running from the queue behaves identically to an ordinary web request, except that the Taskqueue API will reschedule a task that exits with a non-200 response.